# Perl : How to match a parenthesis inside a regexp?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to extract some fields from a fixed format data, which looks like this:

```
G1 = DFF(G2)
```

Say $_ has the above line, and I want to get G1 and G2 after matching it with a suitable reg exp. I'm using this :

```
if (/(w+)\s*=\s*DFF\((w+)\)/)
{     
    print "$1, $2";
}
```

But this isn't printing what I want (prints nothing, which means my pattern is wrong). Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong (pls be patient, this is my first perl program !!)

Comment: You want to say `\w+`, not `w+`.

Comment: Where are you matching the string with the regular expression? Your if condition is just having the regular expression...

Comment: @Cybernate, `$_` is implicit in that expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (/(\w+)\s*=\s*DFF\((\w+)\)/)
```

It's not the parens that are incorrect, it's the word match `\w` that needs an escape.